# AudioKit Output PCM Data In Realtime

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am attempting to use AudioKit 4.x (open to using 5.x beta) on iOS and am unsure of the best approach to accomplish the following:

Play an audio file with NO audile processing while:

1. Merging L+R channels to create mono
2. Applying Low Pass Filter
3. Convert the sample rate from input rate to a very low rate ~ 1kHz
4. Capture PCM data in realtime for transmission over BLE

I have had varying success with parts of this but don't know how to resample and capture the PCM data.  I don't necessarily need code - just pointed in the right direction.